# UnicodeEncodeError while I try to fetch a Chinese String from Tkinter.Entry, in Python

Tags: unicode, tkinter, python-3.4

An UnicodeEncodeError occurred while I tried to fetch a Chinese string from an Entry, an widget from 'tkinter' module. The operation system on which I am working is Windows 7 and the version of Python is Python3.4. The widget works well on English characters. Here is my program.

```
from tkinter import *

class LabelEntry(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, **config):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, **config)
        self.title = title
        self.user_input = StringVar(parent)
        self.pack()
        self.makeWidgets()


    def makeWidgets(self):
        Label(self, text=self.title).pack(side=LEFT)
        ent = Entry(self, textvariable=self.user_input)
        ent.pack(side=RIGHT)
        ent.bind('<Return>', self.onReturnKey)

    def onReturnKey(self, event):
        print(self.user_input.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tkroot = Tk()
    widget = LabelEntry(tkroot, 'corp_title')
    widget.mainloop()
```

Since I do not know how to solve to problem, I try to modify the program. This time, I do not use StringVar to save the string in the Entry, instead, I use Entry.get() to get the value directly. However, same exception occurs after I input a Chinese string. Here is the new program.

```
from tkinter import *

class LabelEntry(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, **config):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, **config)
        self.title = title
        self.pack()
        self.makeWidgets()  

    def makeWidgets(self):
        Label(self, text=self.title).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.ent = Entry(self)
        self.ent.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.ent.bind('<Return>', self.onReturnKey)

    def onReturnKey(self, event):
        print(self.ent.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tkroot = Tk()
    widget = LabelEntry(tkroot, 'corp_title')
    widget.mainloop()
```

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: I have tried to use  the magic string "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" at the head of the program, It does not work. And I have looked for the pydoc on the topic of Entry.get() and Tkinter.StringVar().get(), neither of them has a option on unicode encoding.

Comment: Full traceback? Somewhere in your code or tkinter, someone is trying to coerce a unicode string into an ascii string, and the traceback should tell you where.

Comment: I don't understand. It is works well with Chinese string while I copied the program to IDLE and press F5. Before that I tried to run the program in CMD, and failed as I described above. Very strange! I think it is not a problem on language?

Comment: @Storm-Eyes, `# coding: utf8` only declares the encoding of the source file.  Since your program only contains standard ASCII characters, it will have no effect.

Comment: What is the codepoint of the unicode character you are trying to use? It could be that it is out of range of Tk (the wrapper around tkinter). If the character is above (U+0000-U+FFFF) then it will cause an exception. This might get fixed with Tk 8.7 which is currently in alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Your console may not support, or be correctly configured to support, Chinese characters.  Change:

```
print(self.user_input.get())
```

to:

```
print(ascii(self.user_input.get()))
```

You should see the correct Unicode codepoints displayed.

If you are on Windows, changing Control Panel's `Region and Language`, Administrative, Current language for non-Unicode programs to a Chinese locale will allow Chinese characters to print in the Windows console.

Better yet, display the text in a widget instead of printing to the console.